# Passing information from a java Servlet to the browser in real time

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, push-notification

I have created a dynamic web project in Java. This project consist of an index.html webpage and a java servlet.
The java servlet imports the Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) and gets information (through HTTP requests) from different clients. This is part of the servlet code:

```
@Path("/")
public class HttpServlet {

@GET
@Path("{appID}")
public Response getInformation(@PathParam("appID") String appID) throws IOException {

        return Response.ok().build();

}
```

In addition to that, once I receive a new HTTP request, I would like to push the appID data into the index.html of the same project. Thus, the index.html shows the appID information of those HTTP request in real time using AJAX.

The problem is that I don't know how to send the data from the servlet to the browser since, in this case, there is not any link between the servlet and the HTTP session webpage.

Thanks!